# Unity3D error "Invalid Build path"

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I try to build any type of game using Unity, it is giving me this error:

> Invalid build path: c:/users/dell/desktop/projects/unity projects/fox the game
>   UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()

[image: What the error looks like]

It does this with any path

I can't seem to find any reason for this error. I am building on WebGL with 2D graphics.

Version: Unity 2019.1.1f1 Personal

Comment: Get rid of the spaces in the path.

Answer (score 13):

I don't know why it worked but when I chose "downloads" as the exporting path, the error has gone.

Comment: I had the same error while trying to save on drive D. The error was gone when I saved on C:\Temp.

Comment: This has to be a bug but that seems to be the solution.

Answer (score 6):

Just go to desktop -> create new folder -> and select that folder -> you are done

Answer (score 5):

Just choose a location without space characters on it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Player settings -> other Settings
Under Target Architectures
Uncheck the split APKs by Target Architecture

Answer (score 0):

Just select another path of your project (downloads or in a directory next to your project)

Answer (score 0):

If you are a MacOS user set the path fully. So go to MacBook > Machintosh HD > Users > user and make a folder there.